Trouble with double-precision floats while replicating of one Software's behavior in Python
I struggle with a somewhat a problem for my brain and would appreciate your thoughts and help to resolve this.
I have a software (very very old.. no versions available anymore on the internet) I would like to "replicate" its calculation in python.
This software do (i think) numerical calculation and has functions like pow(x, y), sqrt(x), exp(x), erf(x) and alikes...
I thought, that I'll run into floats/cancellation & overflow problems with my current approach using double-precision, but I didn't thought of it'll be so difficult to figure out for me.
From the start:
the software has input fields for values, for results and for reporting/evaluation of different datasets.
First, the input fields. I noticed, inputs of numbers is handled like this:
+----+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|    |  *positive float* |   *positive int*   |     *neg float*       |     *neg float*    |
+----+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| 1  |        0.9        |          9         |          -0.1         |        -0.9        |
| 2  |        0.99       |         99         |         -0.11         |        -0.99       |
| 3  |       0.999       |         999        |         -0.111        |       -0.999       |
| 4  |       0.9999      |        9999        |        -0.1111        |       -0.9999      |
| 5  |      0.99999      |        99999       |        -0.11111       |      -0.99999      |
| 6  |      0.999999     |       999999       |       -0.111111       |      -0.999999     |
| 7  |    0.999999999    |       9999999      |       -0.1111111      |     -0.9999999     |
| 8  |    0.9999999999   |      99999999      |      -0.11111111      |     -0.99999999    |
| 9  |   0.99999999999   |      999999999     |      -0.111111111     |    -0.999999999    |
| 10 |   0.999999999999  |     9999999999     |     -0.1111111111     |    -0.9999999999   |
| 11 |  0.9999999999999  |     99999999999    |     -0.11111111111    |   -0.99999999999   |
| 12 |  0.99999999999999 |    999999999999    |    -0.111111111111    |   -0.999999999999  |
| 13 | 0.999999999999999 |    9999999999999   |    -0.1111111111111   |  -0.9999999999999  |
| 14 |         1         |   99999999999999   |   -0.11111111111111   |  -0.99999999999999 |
| 15 |        ...        |   999999999999999  |   -0.111111111111111  | -0.999999999999999 |
| 16 |                   |  9999999999999999  |   -0.111111111111111  |         -1         |
| 17 |                   |  99999999999999999 |          ....         |         -1         |
| 18 |                   | 999999999999999999 | 1.11111111111111e+017 |          ...       |
| 19 |                   |       1e+020       | 1.11111111111111e+018 |                    |
| 20 |                   |        ....        | 1.11111111111111e+019 |                    |
| 21 |                   |                    | 1.11111111111111e+020 |                    |
| 22 |                   |                    | 1.11111111111111e+021 |                    |

As it can be seen, the entered values are somewhen truncated or rounded to scientific format with a 3-digit exponent with a small "e". In general, the software can handle the full double-precision float range / large values. I'll show it little bit later...
By looking at this table, i see the border of amount of decimal places for positive int at 18 places, for negative float 13-15 places.. thats the input side.
On the output side, its somehow similar, little bit inconsistent and strange.. So, in 3 Weeks time, I figured out, the output is being rounded to significant 6 decimal places. But not for all value-types the same. I wrote a round_significant() function in Python:
def round_significant_3(x, p):  # third version
    # Set the decimal context precision to 50 digits - precision is not used now.
    # ctx = decimal.getcontext()
    # ctx.prec = 16
    if not isinstance(x, str) and math.isfinite(x):
        x = x.real       # possibly a complex number coming in
        if 10**(-4) < abs(x) < 10**15:
            x_decimal = decimal.Decimal(str(x))
            significant_digits = p - x_decimal.adjusted() - 1
            result_decimal = round((x_decimal), (significant_digits))
            return int(result_decimal) if float(result_decimal).is_integer() else float(result_decimal)
        elif x == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return np.format_float_scientific(x, unique=False, precision= p-1, exp_digits=3, trim="-")
    else:
        return x

So, calling round_significant_3(x, 6) is giving me the proper rounding of values, that I also see in the output of the Software. One thing I really had headache with was the 3-digits-exponent. Python only show 2-digits, where the exponents aren't 3-digits.
+----------+---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
|          |     func      |         result           |       rounded with        |
|          |               |                          | round_significant_3, p=6  |
+----------+---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
| Python   | pow(2, -1000) | 9.332636185032189e-*302* | '9.33264e-302'    (str)   |
| Software | pow(2, -1000) | 9.33264e-*302*           | 9.33264e-302              |
| Python   | pow(2, -100)  | 7.888609052210118e-*31*  | '7.88861e-031'    (str)   |
| Software | pow(2, -100)  | 7.88861e-*031*           | 7.88861e-031              |

to overcome this, I found the numpy's format_float_scientific(x, unique=True, precision= p-1, exp_digits=3, trim="-") where the exponent digits can be set to "3", and also all the trimming of zeros or the precision can be set. This works like intended.

BUT!
I don't know anything about the underlyings of the software and how it does its computation. So, purely out of experiments to find edge cases of the software's functions, I noticed the
edge for integers < 2**(1024), everything above that is being set as +inf... So the handling of the limits/edges is also not python-wise and everything points to double-precision but not above double-precision! .. this ain't my problem right now. I think, it isn't.
The problem, what I can't fully reproduce, occurs when the software displays calculated large numbers with both large, positive and negative exponents (meaning: abs(exponent) > ~200). Then, I have a strange rounding behavior within the software's output. I can partially reproduce it, because it must be caused by float-arithmetic / double precision / cancellation..
With large numbers, sometimes the result is being:
Firstly, rounded to significant
Secondly, ... something happens <-
Third-ly, the rounded to significant value is returned with decimal-places added.
So, it looks like this:
+---------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|     funct     |    y value    |    rounded     |        software       |
|               | for pow(2, y) |  with python   |         Output        |
|               |               |    + signif.   |                       |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| `pow(2, 1000)`  |      1000     | '1.07151e+301' | 1.07151e+301          |
| `pow(2, 999.9)` |     999.9     | '9.99753e+300' | 9.99753000000001e+300 |  \<-
| `pow(2, 999.8)` |     999.8     | '9.32802e+300' | 9.32802000000001e+300 |  \<-
| `pow(2, 999.7)` |     999.7     | '8.70335e+300' | 8.70335000000001e+300 |  \<-
| `pow(2, 999.6)` |     999.6     | '8.12052e+300' | 8.12052000000001e+300 |  \<-
| `pow(2, 999.5)` |     999.5     | '7.57671e+300' | 7.57671e+300          |
| `pow(2, 999.4)` |     999.4     | '7.06932e+300' | 7.06932000000001e+300 |  \<-
| `pow(2, 999.3)` |     999.3     | '6.59591e+300' | 6.59591e+300          |
| `pow(2, 999.2)` |     999.2     | '6.1542e+300'  | 6.1542e+300           |
| `pow(2, 999.1)` |     999.1     | '5.74207e+300' | 5.74207e+300          |

In the rightmost column this behavior can be seen. For certain values '000000001' is added. That happens only with very large numbers. With very small numbers, it also happens, but in the other direction:
+----------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|      funct     |    y value    |    rounded     |        software       |
|                | for pow(2, y) |  with python   |         Output        |
|                |               |    + signif.   |                       |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| `pow(2, -814.6)` |     -814.6    | '6.03901e-246' | 6.03901e-246          |
| `pow(2, -814.5)` |     -814.5    | '6.47245e-246' | 6.47245e-246          |
| `pow(2, -814.4)` |     -814.4    | '6.937e-246'   | 6.93699999999999e-246 |  \<-
| `pow(2, -814.3)` |     -814.3    | '6.03901e-246' | 7.43489e-246          |
| `pow(2, -814.2)` |     -814.2    | '6.47245e-246' | 7.96852e-246          |
| `pow(2, -814.1)` |     -814.1    | '8.54045e-246' | 8.54044999999999e-246 |  \<-
| `pow(2, -814)`   |      -814     | '9.15342e-246' | 9.15341999999999e-246 |  \<-
| `pow(2, -813.9)` |     -813.9    | '9.8104e-246'  | 9.8104e-246           |
| `pow(2, -813.8)` |     -813.8    | '1.05145e-245' | 1.05145e-245          |
| `pow(2, -813.7)` |     -813.7    | '1.12692e-245' | 1.12692e-245          |

I nailed this behavior to floating-point arithmetic precision problem, but can't see the cause, why certain values and not all of them. I can simulate this behavior with numpy's:
np.nextafter(result_float, np.inf) for the very large values, and for the very small values np.nextafter(result_float, -np.inf)
so doing for example:
np.nextafter(round_significant_3(pow(2, 999.7), 6), np.inf) results exactly with "8.70335000000001e+300"
But, if I do this within the round_significant_3() function, this will be applied to all of the results and not just to the certain ones.
The next thing:
If I do calculation of erf(tan(9467.36)) within the software, the output is '-1'. While doing the same in Python with
\_alpha =  2**1023\*(2 - 2**(-52)) # 1.797693134862315e+308, or 
\_alpha = 2\*\*(1024-257\*\_machine_epsilon)
\_machine_epsilon = 2\*\*(-52)

def erf(x):
    x = x.real  # may be complex number comes in
    return math.erf(x)
def tan(x):
    x = x.real
    result = math.tan(x) if abs(x) \<= \_alpha else np.nan   # keep x \< as 2\*\*1024
    return result

returns '-0.9999999999999998', which is just an epsilon of difference to -1:
import sys 
epsilon = sys.float_info.epsilon 
print("Machine epsilon:", epsilon) 
precision = sys.float_info.dig 
print("Precision:", precision) 

-> Machine epsilon: 2.220446049250313e-16 -> Precision: 15
So, obviously, there is some "tolerance" built in into the rounding function of the software (?). To check on that, I did following in the software:
    equal(erf(tan(9467.36)), -1)                                               -\> True  (1)
    equal(erf(tan(9467.36)), -1 - 2.22044604925031e-16)                        -\> False (0)
    equal(erf(tan(9467.36)) - 2.22044604925031e-16, -1 - 2.22044604925031e-16) -\> True  (1)
    equal(erf(tan(9467.36)) + 2.22044604925031e-16, -1 - 2.22044604925031e-16) -\> False (1)
    equal(erf(tan(9467.36)) + 2.22044604925031e-16, -1 + 2.22044604925031e-16) -\> True  (1)

    equal(0, 0)                                                                -\> True  (1)
    equal(0, 0 + 2.22044604925031e-16)                                         -\> False (0)
    equal(0, 0 - 2.22044604925031e-16)                                         -\> False (0)

    *rounding test*:
    0 - 2.22044604925031e-16 / 2    -\>  -1.11022e-016  (half epsilon???)
    0 + 2.22044604925031e-16 / 2    -\>  +1.11022e-016  (half epsilon???)
    0 - 2.22044604925031e-16 \* 2   -\>  -4.44089e-016  (double epsilon?)
    0 - 2.22044604925031e-32        -\>  -2.22045e-032
    0 - 2.21044604925031e-32        -\>  -2.21045e-032
    0 - 2.23044604925031e-32        -\>  -2.23045e-032

    2.22044604925031e-16            -\> 2.22044604925031e-16  no rounding
    2.22044604925031e-16 / 3000     -\> 7.40149e-020          no rounding

    \-1 - 2.22044604925031e-16          -\> -1
    \-1 - 2 \* 2.22044604925031e-16      -\> -1
    \-1 - 3 \* 2.22044604925031e-16      -\> -1
    \-1 - 40 \* 2.22044604925031e-16     -\> -1
    ...
    \-1 - 40000 \* 2.22044604925031e-16  -\> -1
    
    \-1 + 2.22044604925031e-16          -\> -1
    \-1 + 2 \* 2.22044604925031e-16      -\> -1
    \-1 + 3 \* 2.22044604925031e-16      -\> -1
    \-1 + 40 \* 2.22044604925031e-16     -\> -1
    ...
    \-1 + 40000 \* 2.22044604925031e-16  -\> -1

    0 + 40000*2.22044604925031e-16     -\> 8.88178e-012
    0 + 40*2.22044604925031e-16        -\> 8.88178e-015
    0 + 4*2.22044604925031e-16         -\> 8.88178e-016
    0 + 3*2.22044604925031e-16         -\> 6.66134e-016
    0 + 2.22044604925031e-16           -\> 2.22045e-016
...

So strange. I can't see a system in here, except negative value -> round, positive value -> do not round.
So given the few results in tables above, can someone explain me what am I missing here??
I think, the software is using decimals all over. Then, for the output, a conversion to float is made, hence the np.nextafter() is doing that adding '00000001' - the next after value.
I did try the above as described. I tried to use decimals, mpmath .. but did not came along with the usage logic. Also, I somehow have the feeling, its not about the internal calculation of the software. No matter, if it internally uses decimals or floats, the rounding function in the end is the problem.
I really need help in here, because I don't know how to proceed or what else to try. Thank you.

care to share the name of this 'very very old' software, maybe someone else knows about it ....

Its Nutonian Eureqa Formulize II. As I can see, its C++ and uses BOOST for XML serialization. Thus I think my Problem is that the Software is doing fully IEEE754 double Standard, while Python does too - but somehow there are calculation differences. I want to reproduce the software's functions calculation with Python - meehhh.
